# Adding solutions to get a new solution?

Tags: mathematical-physics

Recently I've stumbled upon the same question as here: [What happens to the position function when an oscillator is overdamped and does not have angular frequency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137476/what-happens-to-the-position-function-when-an-oscillator-is-overdamped-and-does/137480#137480?newreg=5ae779c61f28401290f3e36b42a8e437)

And the answer that I preferred (the one by CuriousKev) was perfect until the last sentence, "*Since we can add solutions to get a new solution, the most general is:*

*X = A<sup>−r<sub>1</sub>t</sup> + B<sup>-r<sub>2</sub>t</sup>* "

I've tried searching for the "adding two solutions to get final solution" theory but I either get mistaken for chemistry questions or other unrelated mathematical questions, so could someone link me to the right place or explain this usage of solution(s) addition?

---

I could be posting the question in the wrong place (as in maybe I should ask such question on maths.stackexchange instead?) It is my first question around this website; so apologies in advance.

Comment: It is called superposition and it applies for linear systems

Comment: The answer (by CuriousKev) has the answer to your question: "*Notice your equation of motion is linear in x. So we can take a linear combination of any two solutions and get another one.*" If you have an eom that is linear, you can add two solutions to get a new, third solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! This is simply a feature of linear differential equations. If I have a differential equation with 2 solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$, then $a y_1 + b y_2$ must be a solution. I'll prove that here quickly:

Let's say we have the differential equation
$$y'' + \beta^2 y' = 0$$

If $y_1$ is a solution, then:
$$y_1'' + \beta^2 y_1 = 0$$

and if $y_2$ is a solution, then:
$$y_2'' + \beta^2 y_2 = 0$$

Now, let's say I want to check if $Y = a y_1 + b y_2$ is a solution. If it is, then the following must equal 0:
$$
Y'' + \beta^2 Y \\
= (a y_1 + b y_2)'' + \beta^2 (a y_1 + b y_2) \\
= (a y_1)'' + (b y_2)'' + \beta^2 a y_1 + \beta^2 b y_2 \\
= a y_1'' + b y_2'' + \beta^2 a y_1 + \beta^2 b y_2 \\
= a (y_1'' + \beta^2 y_1) + b (y_2'' + \beta^2 y_2) \\
= a(0) + b(0) \\
= 0
$$

Essentially, **A linear combination of any number of solutions to a linear differential equation must be a solution to that differential equation**

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Wanted to clarify that this is necessarily true only for linear differential equations.